# Largest U.S. cities per state in 1950

Tags: data-request, usa, city, historical, population

I am looking for a data set that contains the largest city for every US American state in 1950. The data should contain the city name, the state name, the population and, if possible, longitude and latitude coordinates for each city.

The data might look similar to [this list](https://www.census.gov/population/www/documentation/twps0027/tab18.txt) but would need to include the largest city in every state.

Alternatively, a data set with the 1000 largest cities in the US as of 1950 would probably be sufficient, too, as it might allow me to reconstruct the largest city in each state manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data you want are [in these files](https://github.com/cestastanford/historical-us-city-populations/tree/master/data).

> The primary source for this data was a US Census Bureau dataset of ~7500 incorporated cities whose populations surpassed 2500 people at some point in their existence. Additional cities were added from a variety of sources (...)

Comment: I looked at the linked dataset and located multiple cases where relatively recent data, e.g. for year 1970, was not available (0s instead). I would recommend loading the data directly from census.gov or american fact finder if you need data for the last few decades.